# How do you export an sqlite database to a csv file on an Android device?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, csv, export

The CSV file will later be sent over a network for storage in external servers.

Answer (score 0):

I use sqlitestudio to export/ import my database to and from csv. http://sqlitestudio.pl/

Answer (score -2):

Open the database;
For every table create a csv file, reading all the rows and exporting them to a file (according the csv format);
Close the database

Comment: @tacone if it was so obvious, why the question?!